# Bootstrap 4 list group item as a form input value?

Tags: php, html

**I'm redoing the whole post since I had hard time explaining the issue or question.**

What this code does:
The user can create a new training session. They can name it and if they want to, they can copy the content from previously created session.

I'm using Bootstrap 4 list group items to show the previous sessions. My problem is that I can not catch the user selection to post the data to activateSaveTrainingSession.php, which includes the SQL query to insert the new data to the database.

I can pass the data from the form to the action php file from inputSessionName -input. As you can see, I've also tried using input type="hidden". It kind of works, but it only uses the $sessionId from the first row it fetches, not the user selection. And thats the problem: how do I catch which list item the user selects, so I can post the data to the activateSaveTrainingSession.php?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <form class="was-validated" action="activateSaveTrainingSession.php" method="post">
            <div class="custom-control">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputSessionName" class="float-left"><?php echo $lang['TRAINING_SESSIONNAME_HEADER'] ?></label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSessionName" name="inputSessionName" placeholder="Example 1" minlength="3" maxLength="128" required>
                    <small id="inputSessionNameHelp" class="form-text text-muted">
                        <?php echo $lang['TRAINING_SESSIONNAME_HELPTEXT'] ?>
                    </small>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h5 class = "mt-3"><?php echo $lang['TRAINING_COPYSESSION_HEADER'] ?></h5>
            <div class="row mt-3">
                <div class="col-lg-6 mb-3">
                    <div class="list-group" id="list-tab" role="tablist">
                        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" id="list-doNotCopy-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-doNotCopy" role="tab" aria-controls="list-doNotCopy">Do not copy</a>
                        <?php
                        $stmt = $link->prepare('SELECT `id`, `sessionName`, `createDate` FROM `trainingSessions` WHERE `userId` = ? ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 5');
                        $stmt->bind_param('i', $currentUserId);
                        $stmt->execute();
                        $stmt->store_result();
                        $stmt->bind_result($sessionId, $sessionName, $sessionNameDate);
                        $sessionCounter = 0;
                        $tabsArray = array();
                        if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
                            while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                                $sessionNameDateFixed = date("d.m.Y", strtotime($sessionNameDate));
                                $sessionCounter += 1;
                                $listId = "list-$sessionId-list";
                                $tabId = "list-$sessionId";
                                array_push($tabsArray, $sessionId)
                                ?>
                                <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="<?php echo $sessionId ?>" data-toggle="list" href="#<?php echo $tabId ?>" role="tab" aria-controls="<?php echo $tabId ?>"><?php echo $sessionName ?><input type='hidden' name='copySession' value='<?php echo $sessionId ?> '/></a>
                                <?php
                            }
                        } else {
                            echo "No results.";
                        }
                        $stmt->close();
                        echo "Displaying last $sessionCounter records.";
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="list-doNotCopy" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-doNotCopy-list">Do not copy data from previous session.</div>
                        <?php
                        foreach ($tabsArray as $session) {
                            $tabsTextArray = array();
                            $stmt = $link->prepare('SELECT trainingSessions.id, workouts.workoutName, exercises.setNumber, exercises.reps, exercises.weights FROM workouts INNER JOIN exercises ON workouts.id = exercises.workoutId INNER JOIN trainingSessions on trainingSessions.id = exercises.sessionId WHERE exercises.userId = ? AND trainingSessions.id = ? ORDER BY exercises.id DESC');
                            $stmt->bind_param('ii', $currentUserId, $session);
                            $stmt->execute();
                            $stmt->store_result();
                            $stmt->bind_result($sessionId, $workoutName, $set, $reps, $weights);
                            if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
                                while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                                    $tabText = "<strong>$workoutName</strong> sarja $set, $reps x $weights kg<br>";
                                    array_push($tabsTextArray, $tabText);
                                }
                            }
                            $listId = "list-$sessionId-list";
                            $tabId = "list-$sessionId";
                            ?>
                            <div class = "tab-pane fade" id="<?php echo $tabId ?>" role = "tabpanel" aria-labelledby = "<?php echo $listId ?>"><?php
                                foreach ($tabsTextArray as $text) {
                                    echo "$text";
                                }
                                ?>
                            </div>
                            <?php
                        }
                        $stmt->close();
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" name="buttonSaveTrainingSession" class="btn btn-success float-left"> 
                <i class="fas fa-sd-card"></i>
                <?php echo $lang['TRAINING_BTN_SAVE'] ?>
            </button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**activateSaveTrainingSession.php**

```
<?php

require_once('config/sql.php');
include_once('config/common.php');
if (!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true) {
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;
}

$currentUserId = $_SESSION["currentUserId"];

$submitButton = strip_tags(trim($_POST['buttonSaveTrainingSession']));
if (isset($submitButton)) {
    $inputSessioName = filter_var(trim($_POST["inputSessionName"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS);
    $copySessionID = filter_var(trim($_POST["copySession"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

    if (empty($inputSessioName) && strlen($inputSessioName) < 3 && $inputSessioName > 128) {
        header("location: training.php?msg=invalidSessionName");
    } else {
        echo "Name: $inputSessioName <br>";
        echo "ID: $copySessionID";
    }
} else {
    header("location: 404.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: Hello,
To better understand your request, can you share more code concerning your sql request, the display of the data and the form?
Thank you

Comment: Excuse me but again, you are talking about an action form. Can you post it in the structure of your code? where do you want to send the information?

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand your problem.

You send in the form several fields:

```
<input type = 'hidden' name = 'copySession' ...>
```

which have the **same name** and not in table form! so it is normal that when receiving the request:

```
$_POST["copySession"]
```

you get **only one and therefore the first**.

If you want to send them all, you have to do:

```
<input type = 'hidden' name = 'copySession[]' ...>
```

and you get the request as an array.

```
foreach($_POST["copySession"] as $sessionId){ ... }
```

If you want to send only one field, you must make them *`disabled`* with javascript in real time during the selection.

For example you put in all fields copySession *`disabled`* and you add a **class** to them. Then you add the **same class** on the button as well and when the user clicks on a button, the field concerned removes the disabled.

With jQuery something like:

```
//Click on button
$('a.specialClass').on('click', function(){

    //Disabled all copySession inputs
    $('input[name="copySession"]').prop('disabled', true);

    //Let the field concerned able to be send 
    $('input.specialClass[name="copySession"]').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! I tried using the table before but I didn't know how to use it in activateSaveTrainingSession.php. I still have a bit hard time understanding the javascript part since it's the one I haven't quite learned yet but I'll try my best. I'll mark this as an answer as soon as I get it done :) But atleast I get all the ID's to the activateSaveTrainingSession.php now.

Comment: Yup after a while trying to get just the selected value to the action.php file, I can't seem to get it work :(

Comment: Show us what the action.php file gets using var_dump($_REQUEST[])

Comment: https://pastebin.com/uFLR6Muk
Name: Test name
For each copySession below:
ID: 4
ID: 3
ID: 2
ID: 1
Var dump below:
array(4) { [0]=> string(2) "4 " [1]=> string(2) "3 " [2]=> string(2) "2 " [3]=> string(2) "1 " }

Comment: You receive with your data a space after the number ([0] => string (2) "4 "). You can see that the value of the keys is string 2 and not string 1. You receive an extra space, which changes the data. Clean it with trim ()

Comment: Thanks, didn't notice that at all! I'll try to figure out where does the extra space come from, I guess that's the main issue here. Even the trimming doesn't help, for some reason it doesn't display anything at all.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't help you anymore, if I don't have all the code